# Разновидность синтаксических ошибок (какое правило нарушается)

Tags: синтаксис, определения, правила, перечисление, типы-ошибок

Как называется вид ошибки в построении предложения, когда одно из перечисляемых шире других?

Например: в доме живут кошки, собаки, хомяки, домашние питомцы

(домашние питомцы фактически охватывают все ранее перечисленные понятия)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь обобщающее словосочетание поставлено в один ряд с однородными членами, которые оно обобщает. Не знаю, есть ли для этой ошибки своё название.

Answer (score 1):

Эту ошибку следует отнести к разряду стилистических.
Здесь  https://www.kadrof.ru/mk/20894 перечислены часто встречающиеся стилистические ошибки. В данном списке, под номером 26, приведен пример ошибки "соединение в одном ряду родовых и видовых понятий", о которой и идет речь в вопросе.

Comment: А что это за источник, эта информация как-то утверждена в академических кругах? Мне эта ошибка стилистической не кажется, скорее – лексика, семантика.  Вот ошибка 15 (согласование падежей) действительно стилистическая. Но, возможно,  это не так, поэтому  и хотелось бы ссылаться на проверенные источники (для однообразия хотя бы). К тому же в названии вопроса  обозначена синтаксическая (грамматическая) ошибка.  Насколько корректна принятая систематизация?

Comment: Не исключено, что этот сайт  https://grammatika-rus.ru/stilisticheskie-oshibki/   является первоисточником того самого «перечня стилистических ошибок». Обсуждаемая ошибка находится на своем (26) месте.

Comment: Спасибо, а они кто? Ведь этот материал должен где-то утверждаться, чтобы он получил авторитетный статус.  Может, это стандарт какой-нибудь из министерства образования?